# Cognos Analytics Upgrade - Replace NOT working with Parameter

Tags: upgrade, cognos

Actually, I am upgrading a Cognos 10.2.2 server (compatibility mode) to Cognos 12.0.1 (Dynamic Query mode).  There was a report working with a data item as:

Text Prompt: 
Prompt Name: ?pFromDate?
Data item: replace(?pFromDate?,',','')
Database: SQL Server 2019
Windows 2022

However, the new Cognos 12.0.1 returns error REPLACE is not supported.
"XQE-PLN-0098 The vendor specific function "replace" is not supported "

IBM Support suggested REPLACE is only for data item.  Is it possible to do something like REPLACE in this case by Cognos internal function?  I have tested REPLACE and TRANSLATE with the same error message.

There are something tried as below:

1. Try to convert all parameter into 1 datatype
2. try REPLACE / TRANSLATE
3. try to add data item to host ?pFromDate? and replace([dummy_query].[FromDate_DataItem],',','')

For item 2 and 3, it is returning the XQE-PLN-0098 error.

Comment: Reproducing the problem using the samples data (GO Sales (query) package would be great) and posting the code here would go a long way towards creating a [minimal, reproducible example[(https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: What database are you using?  Replace is a vendor specific function and if the database did not change I would expect the function to continue to process regardless of the QueryMode.    One thing that does stand out is the number of items you are passing to your replace function.

Usually its repalce(string, character to replace,  replacement character)